# How to get sequence of continous numbers in list if it is in range of X

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures

```
data = [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 22, 24, 26, 29] 
x=2
```

should return:

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6, 7, 9], [22, 24, 26], [29]]
```

My code,

```
from operator import itemgetter  
from itertools import groupby 
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(data), lambda x:x[1]-x[0]):
    res.append(list(map(itemgetter(1), g)))
```

this code returns a consecutive sequence of 1's

```
`([[1, 2], [5, 6, 7], [9], [22], [24], [26], [29]] )`
```

how to modify this code to get the above output or any other method.
any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How to know, how many numbers are to be added in array?

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy for this:

```
from numpy import diff, where, split
result= split(data, where(diff(data)>x)[0]+1 )
print(list(map(list, result)))
```

---

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2], [5, 6, 7, 9], [22, 24, 26], [29]]
```